# Use where clause in temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, temp-tables

I am trying to use where clause in temporary table. Actually i used it but results aren't true. trying to find products between 2 dates but when i use where clause it gets no data.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPCOZGU
(
    ROW INT,
    TEZGAH VARCHAR(50),
    COZGU VARCHAR(50),  
    PERSONEL VARCHAR(50),
    DATE DATETIME,
    FIRE INT,
    FIRE_METRE NUMERIC(25,6)
)
    INSERT INTO #TEMPCOZGU

select row_number() over(order by TEZGAH) AS ROW, TEZGAH, COZGU, PERSONEL, TARIH, FIRE, FIRE_METRE  
from cozgu_fırelerı 
where tezgah = 'M01' and cozgu = 'SAĞ ALT BAĞLANTI'



SELECT  T1.TEZGAH, T1.COZGU, T1.PERSONEL,T1.FIRE, T1.FIRE_METRE, t1.DATE, T2.DATE AS PREVIOUSDATE, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, T2.DATE, T1.DATE), 0) AS GUNFARKI  , SUM(MKARE) AS TOPLAMMKARE
FROM #TEMPCOZGU as t1
left outer join #TEMPCOZGU as t2 on t1.row-1 = t2.row
left outer join HALI_TEZGAH AS TE ON T1.TEZGAH = TE.TEZGAH_NO
LEFT OUTER JOIN HALI_GUNLUK_URETIM AS U ON U.TEZGAH = TE.ID 
--WHERE U.TARIH BETWEEN T1.TARIH AND T2.TARIH
GROUP BY  T1.TEZGAH, T1.COZGU, T1.PERSONEL, T1.DATE,T1.FIRE, T1.FIRE_METRE, T2.DATE

drop table #TEMPCOZGU`
```

Comment: Move the WHERE conditions to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. (As it is now it executes as an inner join...)

Comment: when you used to compare with Date or Datetime you must be carefull about time. e.g. in SQL Date 09/03/2015 considers as 09-03-2015 00:00:00 where we expecting 09-03-2015 23:59:59

Comment: I also tried to move where condition to the on clause. but this time, it got null. But of course value shouldn't be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the datetime values always have the time set to "00:00:00", try

```
SELECT  T1.TEZGAH, T1.COZGU, T1.PERSONEL,T1.FIRE, T1.FIRE_METRE, t1.DATE, T2.DATE AS PREVIOUSDATE, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, T2.DATE, T1.DATE), 0) AS GUNFARKI  , SUM(MKARE) AS TOPLAMMKARE
FROM #TEMPCOZGU as t1
left outer join #TEMPCOZGU as t2 on t1.row-1 = t2.row
left outer join HALI_TEZGAH AS TE ON T1.TEZGAH = TE.TEZGAH_NO
LEFT OUTER JOIN HALI_GUNLUK_URETIM AS U ON U.TEZGAH = TE.ID 
WHERE U.TARIH >= T1.TARIH AND  U.TARIH < DateADD (T2.TARIH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY  T1.TEZGAH, T1.COZGU, T1.PERSONEL, T1.DATE,T1.FIRE, T1.FIRE_METRE, T2.DATE
```

If that's not the case, then your between should have worked in the first place.